# Reproject X coord value in Shapefiles

Tags: qgis, ogr2ogr

I convert Bavarien NAS-Data (DHDN 3 Degree Gauszone 4) via ogr2ogr into shapefiles:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Wien\bin\ogr2ogr.exe" "ESRI Shapefile" -skipfailures Entenhausen.xml
```

This seems to work perfectly, but on loading Data from other sources I found out that the X-Coordinate value in the converted files is 6 digits long (548521,69) whereas the Y-Value is 7 digits long (5376490,59) - the leading digit of the x value (wich specifies the Gauss-Krüger zone 4) present in data from other sources is missing.

Is there any (easy to follow) possibility either in ogr2ogr or qgis to reproject the x-values? I think ogr2org would be better as there are quite a lot of shapefiles.

Comment: If it's EPSG:31468, then yes, it should have a leading 4 for the easting (X) values. Is there any metadata about the coordinate reference system for the input data?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [page about NAS (in German)](http://www.lgn.niedersachsen.de/portal/live.php?navigation_id=11056&article_id=51569&_psmand=35) the leading zone number is not included.

So you have to create a custom CRS without it:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs
```

For ogr2ogr, use:

```
ogr2ogr -f SQLITE -skipfailures -s_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs EPSG:31468 out.sqlite lurchingen_4.4.gml
```

to get coordinates for the [test data](http://vermessung.bayern.de/service/download/testdaten/ALKIS.html) that match the reality:

[image]

Note that I used a spatialite database to get all layers in one file without truncated column names.

You might get further help from

http://www.gdal.org/drv_nas.html

http://trac.wheregroup.com/PostNAS

http://trac.wheregroup.com/PostNAS/wiki/SchrittfuerSchritt

http://trac.wheregroup.com/PostNAS/wiki

All in German, because it is a German data exchange service.

Comment: Thank you very much for the Information that did the trick. I tried SQLite before and yesterday again. The Problem with SQLite, which I really like, is that conversion seems to be painfully slow - the conversion for one NAS-Datafile took 13 hours.
Does anybody know if there is any way to Speed things up?